# Using dynamic styles in react native

Tags: react-native

I've a couple of buttons in my react native app, on pressing any button, color should change. Code is as given below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      clicks: 0,
      show: true,
      isbuttonpress: false
    };
  }

  onButtonState = () => {
      this.setState({isbuttonpress: true});
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ [styles.container] }>
        <Text style= { [styles.header] }>How likely is it that you would recommend this company to a friend or colleague?</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight style = { [styles.buttonContainer, this.state.isbuttonpress?styles.gobackred:styles.goback] } onPress = { () => this.onButtonState() }>
          <Text style = { styles.gobacktext }>0</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style = { [styles.buttonContainer, this.state.isbuttonpress?styles.gobackred:styles.goback] } onPress = { () => this.onButtonState() }>
          <Text style = { styles.gobacktext }>1</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style = { [styles.buttonContainer, this.state.isbuttonpress?styles.gobackred:styles.goback] } onPress = { () => this.onButtonState() }>
          <Text style = { styles.gobacktext }>2</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style = { [styles.buttonContainer, this.state.isbuttonpress?styles.gobackred:styles.goback] } onPress = { () => this.onButtonState() }>
          <Text style = { styles.gobacktext }>3</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style = { [styles.buttonContainer, this.state.isbuttonpress?styles.gobackred:styles.goback] } onPress = { () => this.onButtonState() }>
          <Text style = { styles.gobacktext }>4</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style = { [styles.buttonContainer, this.state.isbuttonpress?styles.gobackred:styles.goback] } onPress = { () => this.onButtonState() }>
          <Text style = { styles.gobacktext }>5</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight style = { [styles.nextContainer, styles.goback] } onPress = { () => this.onNextButtonState() }>
          <Text style = { styles.gobacktext }>Next</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
    buttonContainer: {
    height:45,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom:20,
    width:45,
  }, gobackred: {
    backgroundColor: "#00a2b2",
  },
  goback: {
    backgroundColor: "#00b5ec",
  },
  gobacktext: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  nextContainer: {
    height:45,
    marginTop: 15,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom:20,
    width:250,
    borderRadius:30,
  }
})
```

Layout is as given below:
[image: survey]
Whenever any option is selected, color of that button should change. But in my code, color of all buttons changes when clicked on any button. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's because you are using the same state value to determine the styles for every button. Each button would require its own state value.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you used one state `this.state.isbuttonpress` for all button try to make the component of this code.

your TouchableHighlight Component

**DemoButton.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";

export default class DemoButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isbuttonpress: false };
  }
  onButtonState = () => {
    this.setState({ isbuttonpress: !this.state.isbuttonpress });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.isbuttonpress ? "red" : "blue" }}
          onPress={this.onButtonState}
        >
          <Text>{this.props.buttonTitle}</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import DemoButton from "./DemoButton";

export default class Heal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isbuttonpress: false };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header />
        <DemoButton buttonTitle="0"/>
        <DemoButton buttonTitle="1"/>
        <DemoButton buttonTitle="2"/>
        <DemoButton buttonTitle="3"/>
        <DemoButton buttonTitle="4"/>
        <DemoButton buttonTitle="5"/>
      </View> 
  )
  }
  }
```

Comment: You mean that I should create a component for each `TouchableHighlight` and add it to `App.js`?

Comment: @Ajay Kulkarni No. Just pass props which you want to pass in that component.
just use a single component for multiple buttons.
I have changed my code just check and try that.